# How to dynamically assign columns to a PyTables IsDescription class?

Tags: python, pytables

Let's say I have a PyTables description class:

```
In [1]: import tables as tb
        class DataDescr(tb.IsDescription):
            timestamp = tb.Time64Col(pos=0)
            value_b = tb.Float32Col(pos=2)
```

Now I assign `value_a` dynamically. I need to do this because the shape of this column depends on some user input.

```
In [2]: DataDescr.value_a = tb.Float32Col(pos=1, shape=given_shape)
```

But when viewing a table made with this description, I don't see the new column.

```
In [3]: h5file = tb.open_file('goodstuff.h5', mode='w')
        table = h5file.create_table('/', 'data', DataDescr)
        table
Out[3]: /data (Table(0,)) ''
          description := {
          "timestamp": Time64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=0),
          "value_b": Float32Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=1)}
          byteorder := 'little'
          chunkshape := (5461,)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options for this (see [`File.create_table()`](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/file_class.html#tables.File.create_table)).

## Option 1: Add class attribute with `IsDescription.columns`

`IsDescription` objects have a `columns` attribute that stores column information in a dictionary, which can be used for dynamic assignment. As in the question, start with a mostly-complete class...

```
class DataDescr(tb.IsDescription):
    timestamp = tb.Time64Col(pos=0)
    value_b = tb.Float32Col(pos=2)
```

...then add the missing attribute.

```
DataDescr.columns['value_a'] = tb.Float32Col(pos=1, shape=(3, 2))
```

---

## Option 2: Use dictionary description

Rather than a class description, start with a dictionary description...

```
data_descr = dict(
    timestamp=tb.Float64Col(pos=1),
    value_b=tb.Float32Col(pos=2),
)
```

...then add an entry to the dictionary.

```
data_descr['value_a'] = tb.Float32Col(pos=1, shape=(3, 2))
```

---

## Option 3: Create NumPy dtype description all at once

Since NumPy dtypes don't support item assignment, this method requires creating the description all at once. If this is a problem, options 1 and 2 are available.

```
data_descr = np.dtype([
    ('timestamp', np.float64),
    ('value_a', (np.float32, (3, 2))),
    ('value_b', np.float32),
])
```

---

## [Maybe dangerous] Option 4: Modify shape of dict entry

I'll mention a final option, which is not necessarily supported. Therefore, it may be better to stay away from this option.

After starting with a complete dictionary with no sizes specified...

```
data_descr = dict(
    timestamp=tb.Float64Col(pos=1),
    value_a=tb.Float32Col(pos=1),
    value_b=tb.Float32Col(pos=2),
)
```

...modify the shape of the `'value_a'` entry.

```
data_descr['value_a'].shape = (3, 2)
```

**NOTE: This doesn't work with class descriptions, for reasons unbeknownst to me.**

```
class DataDescr(tb.IsDescription):
    timestamp = tb.Time64Col(pos=0)
    value_a = tb.Float32Col(pos=1)
    value_b = tb.Float32Col(pos=2)

DataDescr.columns['value_a'].shape = (3, 2)

h5file = tb.open_file('goodstuff.h5', mode='w')
table = h5file.create_table('/', 'data', DataDescr)

row = table.row
row['value_a'] = np.ones((3, 2)) * 5
row.append()
```

Results in:

```
TypeError: invalid type (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>) for column ``value_a``
```

Comment: Alternately, you can programatically create a Numpy dtype to define the table description instead of using `tb.IsDescription`. Your dtype for all 3 columns would look like this: `tb_dt = np.dtype([('timestamp', np.float64), ('value_a', (np.float32, (3,2))), ('value_b', np.float32)])`. Then, reference `tb_dt ` when you create the table. Columns will be in the same order as the dtype.

Comment: Thanks @kcw78, that's probably a better solution. I'll add it to my answer. Looks like there's also the possibility of using a dictionary: http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/file_class.html#tables.File.create_table

Comment: Yes, there are 5 ways to define the Table. The options are defined in the Pytables docs for `File.create_table()` (see the `description` argument). I tend to use Numpy dtypes b/c I exchange a lot of data between HDF5 and Numpy arrays. In fact, if you load your table data into a Numpy structured array, you can reference it with the `description=` or `obj=` argument and define the table and load the data at the same time. :-) Pytables uses the dtype of the array. That's my preferred way to create tables.